# Initialise AOS - Animate on scroll library in Angular Universal Server Side Rendering

Tags: javascript, angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, aos.js

I've implemented AOS - Animate on scroll library into my project to deal with the animations. But as I convert my Angular project into Angular universal. Error start popping.

```
ERROR ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at n (/Users/syahiruddin/RVI/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:16908:14433)
    at Object._ [as init] (/Users/syahiruddin/RVI/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:16908:1386)
    at AppComponent.ngOnInit (/Users/syahiruddin/RVI/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:106:42)
    at callHook (/Users/syahiruddin/RVI/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:149051:22)
    at callHooks (/Users/syahiruddin/RVI/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:149020:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (/Users/syahiruddin/RVI/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:148971:9)
    at refreshView (/Users/syahiruddin/RVI/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:156008:21)
    at renderComponentOrTemplate (/Users/syahiruddin/RVI/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:156107:9)
    at tickRootContext (/Users/syahiruddin/RVI/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:157338:9)
    at detectChangesInRootView (/Users/syahiruddin/RVI/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:157363:5)
```

I could not locate the document that is not defined by the error.

Please if someone could shine the light to it.

Here is how I implemented AOS into the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SeoService } from './core/services/seo.service';
//  TODO: FIX AOS for angular universal
import * as AOS from 'aos';
@Component({
  selector: 'rvi-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private seo: SeoService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.seo.initDefaultMetaTags();
    // ERROR ReferenceError: document is not defined
    //  TODO: fix this!!
    AOS.init({ once: true, duration: 1000 });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a caveat and just a workaround, but I'm able to bypass the error by wrapping it with Angular "isPlatformBrowser" from @angular/common.

Here is the solution:

1 import PLATFORM_ID from '@angular/core'

```
import { ..., PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
```

2 Inject in the component constructor where you have to init the AOS

```
constructor(..., @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object)
```

3 Wrap the AOS.init with this if statement:

```
if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) { AOS.init({ once: true, duration: 1000 }); })
```